# Python & BeautifulSoup beginner: how do I extract a tag out of this code

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm looking for a bit of guidance here. I'm completely new to Python, BS, Selenium, etc so please go easy on me.

My ISP doesn't provide alerts for my internet usage and I wanted to create my own monitoring for this. I managed to scrape the page I need using selenium and BeautifulSoup but now I'm a bit stuck. I have a container that has the following HTML code in it:

```
[<div class="usage_circle"> <center>
<div data-perc="69" data-transitiongoal="0.69" data-usage="150.29"> 
</div> </center></div>]
```

I'd like to extract the `data-usage` value of 150.29. I've tried using the `findAll` function (previously used to get the above HTML), but it doesn't work in this case.

Could anyone guide me as to what I need to do to get this number into a variable?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Follow the examples in the documentation and adapt to suit?

Comment: I've been looking at the BS documentation for the past 45 minutes to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In BeautifulSoup you can find all tags with "data-usage" attribute like this:

```
e = soup.findAll(attrs={"data-usage" : True})
```

And then getting value of attribute will be easy, For your first match it will be:

```
e[0]["data-usage"]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Sadiq. It worked. I kept trying something like e["data-usage"] and didn't understand why it didn't work. Can you please explain shortly why I need to use the index [0] too?

Comment: findAll method returns a list of tags that have "data-usage" attribute(Most likely, in this case, this list contains only one tag), index [0] means first tag in that list.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of problem is a great use case for the interactive Python prompt. Save some html, open the file, and mess around with the object until you can find a solution.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html#interactive-mode

The tutorial really does provide you all you need:

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

In Selenium, you can usually find things using the webdriver and not have to directly invoke beautifulsoup at all.

In your case, you could grab that block by class name and/or get the data-usage field via a tag name (it has been a while, don't quote me on the exact function delclarations).

If you want to use BeautifulSoup for whatever reason, this example will work:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """[<div class="usage_circle"> <center>
<div data-perc="69" data-transitiongoal="0.69" data-usage="150.29"> 
</div> </center></div>]"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'lxml')
soup.div.center.div["data-usage"]
```

The more important lesson is *how* to find that tree, though. Get something like [jupyter](https://jupyter.org/) if you want something prettier than a plain interactive console, but I intentionally used only code copied and minimally-altered from the quickstart.